# Not all Loops processed, only 5655 out of 13200

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have 2 javascript loops, one nested in the other, that does an AJAX call to the serverside. The loops generate a pair of numbers (latlng coordinates), which is then passed to the server via `.getJSON()` where it will be inserted into a MySQL table.

**Problem:** The script runs for about 6 minute, with a total of 13200 AJAX calls. In chrome's webdeveloper tools, it says `5656/13646 requests 536.20KB/2.15MB`. When I check the tables for the inserted entries, I only see 5655 rows! What happened to the rest?

**JS Code**

```
for(var i = 0; i < 110; i++) {
    var lat_current = lat_start + lat_increment * i;

    for(var j = 0; j < 120; j++) {

        // Do some calculations
        // More code here...

        // Insert LatLng into database
        $.getJSON(base_url + 'insert_latlng_to_crawl', 
            {
                lat: lat_current,
                lng: lng_current
            }, 
            function(json){
            });

    }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not the server dying out? I would check the response for a handful of the ajax requests

Comment: The rest of your requests are likely sitting in a queue. AJAX requests are _asynchronous_, or **non** blocking, so your loop will execute as fast as it can, while the actual requests pile up in the background.

Comment: There are no new rows being added to the table after waiting for 10 mins. How can I tell whether its the Chrome browser limiting the number of AJAX calls or the server rejecting the?

Comment: You would be much better off keeping everything client side until the calculations are finished and then making one big http request, then making 13200 individual requests. You're probably over 5 MB in HTTP headers alone the way you have it, and if you have cookies you could be transferring something like 50 MB without any use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a javascript object, then pass it to the server and process it server-side

```
 var coords=Array();//Create an array to store the calculations
 for(var i = 0; i < 110; i++) {
    var lat_current = lat_start + lat_increment * i;

    for(var j = 0; j < 120; j++) {

    // Do some calculations
    // More code here...

    // append the results to the array
    coords.push({lat: lat_current, lng: lng_current});


}

//Make the ajax call to the server, sending the completed Array JSON encoded
coords= JSON.stringify(coords);
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',//you should send big chunks of data via POST
  url: url,
  data: coords,
  success: success,
  dataType: JSON
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be counting the return values.

5655/13200

5655 is what you sent and the number after the / is total (which includes returned values which is 2x your first number). Sent and received json values. Im assuming a success status of some sort?

Also the question is how many duplicate values are being inserted into your table? Do you have unique keys on your table?

Comment: There are 3 cols in the tables, first is a `id` column that is a unique key col and auto_increment. There are no duplicate checks server side. Does this mean the browser only sent 5655 requests to the server instead of 13200 as the loops above should sent, meaning that Chrome is limiting the number of requests being sent??

Comment: I think the second number is total traffic number (sent and recieved requests). Can you print to screen or file a counter to see actually how many requests were made?

Comment: What I mean is that jSON will return an object (or success) to your ajax request correct?

Comment: Should I put the counter in the callback function of `.getJSON()` or outside it?

Comment: You only need it in your inner loop. im assuming ignore the call for now. you can put it right at the top if the inner loop.

Comment: Just did the counter thing in the inner loop. Counter says 13200.

Comment: Ok try one more thing. try the .success or .error callbacks on your call.

Comment: .success(function() { alert("second success"); })
.error(function() { alert("error"); })

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12130/discussion-between-shawn-and-nyxynyx)